# ON/OFF rocker switches - convention about which side should be top/bottom?

Tags: switches, toggle-switch, alignment

Is there a technical convention (maybe unofficial) as to which side to mount upwards ? I imagine there could be such a guideline, because the marking could rub off or users might have impaired vision.

I know this might attract opinions, but those [should be shared here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/36207/which-way-should-be-on-for-a-switch). I am asking from the device manufacturers' perspective (the one who builds the switch into their chassis), specifically if there is a safety norm or similar that mandates one particular orientation.

I admit that I have done it as I saw fit in the past, with no-one complaining. But I have doubts that this is universal.

[image][image]

Comment: Not sure the manufacturer cares which way round you fit it, that's why it has O and I instead of OFF and ON.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is a standard way to mount rocker and toggle switches. Unfortunately, that standard is different between the USA and the UK. USA is on up, UK is on down.

I don't know about the rest of the world, it would interesting if locals of other countries/continents would add in comments what their local standard is.

Comment: @Neil_UK I am not sure it is federal standard, but my flat's switches in Germany comply with UK logic.

Answer (score 1):

From a safety perspective, should the device normally be off or on?  Because it seems like with on up, the user has to intentionally turn the device on, and accidentally turning it on would be unlikely.  While anything brushing against the switch or falling on it would tend to turn it off.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you want the ON to be at the top or up and the OFF to be at the bottom or down.  This makes sense from a human factors perspective but there is no hard and fast rule that says you must do it one way or another.

Personally I find it frustrating when power switches are installed with ON in the bottom or down position as it's not intuitive.

Technically, it doesn't matter at all since the switch doesn't care.

Comment: Really? I'd say the opposite, a downward motion turns on a toggle or lever switch so I'd expect it to do the same on a rocker. Every light switch and power socket in the UK has the bottom pressed in for ON.

Comment: Perhaps you're from "down under" then where they do things backward.

Comment: It's a personal opinion. I like when the ON position is up. Down motion turns a device off.

Comment: Re: UK. No, I think that it's a legal Wiring Regulations thing. It means that you can tell a switch state in the dark/or if blind.

Comment: It’s my experience (from operating light switches all over the world) that down is on everywhere except North America.  You are free to hedge your bets and orient the switch sideways.

Comment: Light switches in Czech Republic are regulated by norm ČSN 33 2130. ON is up, OFF is down. I feel like having OFF down is also better for "emergencies" (if I need to turn something off very quickly). It feels faster (and natural) to switch from ON to OFF position.

Comment: @Frog Which way would you suggest mounting it sideways, though?

Comment: @Spehro Pefhany good question although I’m not sure whether you’re asking in jest.  Intuitively (to me anyway) away from the middle of the appliance would be off.

Comment: For heavens sake, just replace it with a push-button latching switch mislabelled with a standby icon! :-)